# Ignore SuperClass

Tags: jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I'm using a class that extends a JavaFx's component

```
public class MyClass extends Pane {}
```

I want to serialize that class only and not the Pane superclass.

As Jaxb does not support it, I'm using Eclipselink MOXy to achieve that:

**marshaller**

```
Map<String, Source> metadataSource = new HashMap<String, Source>();
metadataSource.put("com.myapp", new StreamSource(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/myapp/myclass.xml")));

Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, metadataSource);

JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {MyClass.class}, properties);
Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
m.marshal(new MyClass(), new File("test.xml"));
```

**myclass.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings 
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    version="2.3">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="javafx.scene.layout.Pane" xml-transient="true" />
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

But i'm getting this error :

> javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: 
>    Exception Description: The java-type with package [javafx.scene.layout] is not allowed in the bindings file keyed on package [com.myapp].
>    - with linked exception:
>   [Exception [EclipseLink-50037] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JAXBException

I've spent hours to find some information but found none..

Any help would be appreciated !

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use MOXy's external mapping document to specify that the super type is `java.lang.Object` instead of `Pane`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings 
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="com.example">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="MyClass" super-type="java.lang.Object"/>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

**Answer  to Related Question**

- [NPE when using MOXy's meta data with a class that implements java.util.Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075634/npe-when-using-moxys-meta-data-with-a-class-that-implements-java-util-map/10091556#10091556)